# date and week name and month in datepicker

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

how to get this type of result using bootstrap datepicker

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJTAh.jpg)

start with the current date, week name, and month name in each div. I will use this as a slider

Comment: Please, [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), [Please do not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.